# How do you retrieve a single post on AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to pull a `single-post` request (i.e. grabbing a single entry from my back-end database) using Angular.  But I was unable to understand the actual concept behind pulling data from a `JSON` file through a `GET()` request.

**Example :**

within the `controller.js / services.js`, what should be done to pull all data from a single-post, such as `/portfolio/design/1`, using either `$xhr` or `angular.service()`.

I've attempted to read through the [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/#!/api/angular.service.$resource) and also the [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/#!/tutorial), but I think I wasn't able to wrap my mind around how to actually go about doing it.

I sincerely hope someone can help provide a simple example to help me along my problem.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is to use the $xhr object.  For example:

// in controllers.js

```
function ItemController($xhr){
    var self = this;
    self.key = this.params.id;

    $xhr('GET', 'api/items/' + self.id, function(code, data) {
        self.item = data;
    });
}

// in services.js

angular.service('myApp', function($route, $location, $window) {
    $route.when('/item/:id', 
          {template: 'partials/showItem.html', controller: ItemController});
    // other logic for routing
}

// in partials/showItem.html

<h3>Now Viewing {{item.name}}</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks.. it helped.. Sorry I'm unable to up-vote your answer at the moment.

Comment: The answer looks correct, but I'm not sure what purpose the myApp controller serves in it (I see what it does; it just looks irrelevant).

Comment: I was just trying to show how to get the parameter (item id) to the controller. But you're right, it's not necessary and would require a little more to be a full example.

Comment: Looks like the `$xhr` service has been changed to the [`$http` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http).